# How to get the selected text in android webview

Tags: android, webview, highlight

I need to get the selected text from webview and have to highlight the text permanently. I tried as selecting the text and while i am attempting to get the text using clipboard it showing me null pointer exception at "clipboard.getText()". I have tried code as

```
ClipboardManager mClipboard =
        (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);

 KeyEvent shiftPressEvent = new KeyEvent(0, 0, KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN,
                                                    KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SHIFT_LEFT, 0, 0);
shiftPressEvent.dispatch(webview);
 if(mClipboard!=null)
     {
       String text = mClipboard.getText().toString();
       Toast.makeText(this, "select_text_now     "+text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }
```

I need to get the selected text for highlight futher..please help me..

Comment: an error log would be much appreciated

Comment: Its null pointer exception at String text = mClipboard.getText().toString();

Comment: mClipboard.getText() if this doen't contain any values then it will through nu point exception, may be you can put an if condition to check the getText() methord id returning a string or not, correct me if i am wrong

Comment: null pointer exception occurs at Android4.0 but in android2.2 its  showing correctly.i dont know why this happening..

Comment: String text = (mClipboard.getText() != null) ? mClipboard.getText().toString() : "";  this is not a solution for ur problem but null point exception can be avoided, thanks

Comment: Do you found any way to get selected word from javascript that window.getSelection() returning null in android

Comment: @Dainel no i didnt find the solution for this.

Comment: me also facing the same problem tried a lot of things but all are useless still returning null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have filed an Android bug for this: [Issue 24842: WebView should make getSelection public](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=24842).  If you look at the ticket, you'll see some various workarounds.

Note that the code you posted is roughly similar to emulateShiftHeld which is deprecated in 4.0, which is probably why it is working in 2.2 and not in 4.0.

Comment: Any another alternative to get the selected word with tag name and id in android webview