# how to get the selected text from web view in android

Tags: android, select, text, webview

i am building an app where i need to get the selected text from the web view. Also tried with reflection but its not working with android 3.1+. So any one has any idea how it will be done .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9481169/how-to-get-the-selected-text-in-android-webview

Comment: any other solution to that because window.getSelection is also not working on it