# Find count of particular text in webview in android

Tags: android, webview

I need to find particular text in webview but i can not able to do it.
findall is deprecated  after api level 16 and we need to use findAllAsync.
we can also use WebView.FindListener.
Earlier i was used findall and it work fine but it not work in kitkat and lollipop. I have tried with findAllAsync but i can not able to find count of any particular text.
my code is here :

```
@Override
public void onFindResultReceived(int activeMatchOrdinal,
        int numberOfMatches, boolean isDoneCounting) {
    if (isDoneCounting) {
        updateMatchCount(activeMatchOrdinal, numberOfMatches,
                numberOfMatches == 0);

    }
    Log.e("test", "data ::" + numberOfMatches);

}

public void findAll() {
    if (webviewdevelopment == null) {
        throw new AssertionError(
                "No WebView for FindActionModeCallback::findAll");
    }
    CharSequence find = "Following";
    if (0 == find.length()) {
        webviewdevelopment.clearMatches();
        mMatchesFound = false;
        webviewdevelopment.findAll(null);
    } else {
        mMatchesFound = true;
        mNumberOfMatches = 0;
        webviewdevelopment.findAllAsync(find.toString());

    }

    Log.e("test", "data ::" + mNumberOfMatches);

}

public void updateMatchCount(int matchIndex, int matchCount,
        boolean isEmptyFind) {
    if (!isEmptyFind) {
        mNumberOfMatches = matchCount;
        mActiveMatchIndex = matchIndex;
        updateMatchesString();
    } else {

        mNumberOfMatches = 0;
    }
}

private void updateMatchesString() {
    if (mNumberOfMatches == 0) {

    } else {

        Log.e("test", "data ::" + mNumberOfMatches + ","
                + mActiveMatchIndex + 1 + "," + mNumberOfMatches);

    }

}

private void findNext(boolean next) {
    if (webviewdevelopment == null) {
        throw new AssertionError(
                "No WebView for FindActionModeCallback::findNext");
    }
    if (!mMatchesFound) {
        findAll();
        return;
    }
    if (0 == mNumberOfMatches) {
        // There are no matches, so moving to the next match will not do
        // anything.
        return;
    }
    webviewdevelopment.findNext(next);
    updateMatchesString();
}

@Override
public void onFindResultReceived(int activeMatchOrdinal,
        int numberOfMatches, boolean isDoneCounting) {
    if (isDoneCounting) {
        updateMatchCount(activeMatchOrdinal, numberOfMatches,
                numberOfMatches == 0);

    }
    Log.e("test", "data ::" + numberOfMatches);

}
```

anybody have any demo please provide me, thanks

Answer (score 5):

Use this in your code to search for the string required.

```
webview.findAllAsync("Your String");
```

than add FindListener to WebView

```
webview.setFindListener(new FindListener() {

    @Override
    public void onFindResultReceived(int activeMatchOrdinal, int numberOfMatches, boolean isDoneCounting) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Matches: " + numberOfMatches, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```