# webview show popup options android

Tags: android, webview

I need to provide options as shown in below image when user select text from webview.

[image]

Which method should I override to provide options?

Answer (score 0):

Copy functionality in a `WebView` is available by default in Android 3.0 and above.  To enable copy in version below 3.0, there is a little code that has to be added.  The first thing I did was add a Copy button to my `Actionbar` at the bottom of the view.

Check out the [Copy Text in a WebView in Android](http://android-ed.blogspot.in/2012/10/copy-text-in-webview-in-android-23-and.html?m=1)

Below is the code to show how to use:

```
public class TryDemoActivity extends Activity implements
OnClickListener {
    private WebView webview1;
    private Button copyButton;
    private Button pasteButton;
    private Button highlightButton;
    private ClipboardManager clipboard;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    webview1 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    copyButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.copy);
    pasteButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.paste);

    webview1.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/1.1.html");
    clipboard =(ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
    copyButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    pasteButton.setOnClickListener(this);
}
private void emulateShiftHeld(WebView view)
{
    try
    {
        KeyEvent shiftPressEvent = new KeyEvent(0, 0, KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN,
KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SHIFT_LEFT, 0, 0);
    shiftPressEvent.dispatch(view);

    registerForContextMenu(view);
    Toast.makeText(this, "select_text_now", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("dd", "Exception in emulateShiftHeld()", e);
    }
}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId())
    {
        case R.id.copy:
            emulateShiftHeld(webview1);
        break;
        case R.id.paste:
        Toast.makeText(this, clipboard.getText(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;
    }
   }
 }
```

**EDITED:**

**Note :** The code **emulateShiftHeld** which is deprecated in 4.0, which is probably why it is working in 2.2 and not in 4.0.

Check out the [Post](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=24842)  which i found [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9481169/how-to-get-the-selected-text-in-android-webview)

Comment: thanks 4 reply. but in android 4.0 it's not allow me to select.