# How to get Selected Text in WebView Android

Tags: android, webview

I am developing an application in which I need the get the selected text.

I have a custom contextual action bar, that shows up when user selects a text in webview. I want to get highlighted text under selection handlers, on click of my action bar button.

Question was previously asked,
[How to get the selected text in android webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9481169/how-to-get-the-selected-text-in-android-webview).

But had no solution.

I am trying something like myWebView.getSelection()

Comment: I think you should review this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22336903/use-a-custom-contextual-action-bar-for-webview-text-selection

Answer (score 9):

I posted an answer to a similar question. Sharing it here for quick access to the answer.

For API >= 19 you can use `evaluateJavascript`

```
mWebview.evaluateJavascript("(function(){return window.getSelection().toString()})()",
new ValueCallback<String>()
{
    @Override
    public void onReceiveValue(String value)
    {
        Log.v(TAG, "Webview selected text: " + value);
    }
});
```

For API < 19 you can use `evaluateJavascript` you use the `loadUrl` method like below:

```
mWebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebview.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(), "javascriptinterface");
```

Then when you want to get the selection use the following:

`mWebview.loadUrl("javascript:javascriptinterface.callback(window.getSelection().toString())");`

And define a WebAppInterface class as below:

```
public class JavaScriptInterface
{
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void callback(String value)
    {
        Log.v(TAG, "SELECTION:" + value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Addition *Mahendra Liya* answer:
Also for API >=19 you need to enable JavaScript:

```
WebSettings settings = yourWebview.getSettings();
settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```